# how to rename password label on user edit page in Drupal?

Tags: theming

I would like to change labels only on user edit page. String overrides module would not work because it would rename all labels (user register and user edit). I tried the following:

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if ($vars['template_files'][2] == 'page-user-edit') {
    $vars['content'] = str_replace('Password', 'New Password', $vars['content']);
    $vars['content'] = str_replace('Confirm password', 'Confirm new password', $vars['content']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're willing to do it in a module (you mentioned String Overrides module) you can easily do it with a simple [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in a small custom module.

```
function mymodule_form_user_edit_form_alter($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['desired_element']['#label'] = t('My label');
  return $form;
}
```

This method uses [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7). This way you'll be able to set individual labels as you see fit, though.

Comment: form_alter didn't work for me because form doesn't expose label

Comment: The form should definitely allow access to the #label property as shown above. try printing out the array ($form) so you can see everything contained in it.

Comment: I printed form to a log with watchdog, bud I did not find #label there

Comment: You definitely cannot edit the password label using just hook_form_alter(). See other answers below for the correct hooks to use.

Answer (score 5):

The password inputs are in fact a separate form element (`password_confirm` -- [Form API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#password_confirm)) and although it is themable (see [theme_password_confirm](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_password_confirm/6)), all you can influence is the description, prefix/postfix and element title.

The real work happens in [expand_password_confirm](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/expand_password_confirm/6), which in turn is a process function specified in [system_elements](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_elements/6). The latter is an implementation of [hook_elements](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_elements/6) and it lets Drupal know how to handle various form elements.

Luckily, one can use `hook_elements()` to specify custom form elements and that is the one you can use to override the system processing for the password_confirm element.

A sample implementation follows:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_elements()
 * @see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_elements/6
 */
function mymodule_elements() {
  $type['password_confirm']['#process'][] = 'mymodule_process_password_confirm';
  return $type;
}

/**
 * Do a bit of processing for the password_confirm element.
 * Original processing happens in expand_password_confirm()
 */
function mymodule_process_password_confirm($element) {
  // check if we the parent element is 'account'. On the user edit page, that is the case
  // Of course, one could use arg() to check the path too
  if ($element['#array_parents'][0] == 'account') {
    $element['pass1']['#title'] = 'New password';
    $element['pass2']['#title'] = 'Confirm new password';
  }

  return $element;
}
```

Please note this is based on Drupal 6.
In Drupal 7, `hook_elements()` became [hook_element_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/7) because there is a proper alter hook, [hook_element_info_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/7)

Comment: Actually, I managed to get it changed  in MYTHEME_password_confirm, all I had to do was change $element['pass1']['#title'] and then re-render the elements. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Put the below code in your theme folder's template.php file. Just double check that your template.php already has an existing `YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars)` function, in that case, only add what is inside the function below.

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

 $form['account']['current_pass']['#title'] = 'New Label';

}

function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars){

$vars['page']['content']['system_main']['account']['pass']['pass1']['#title'] = 'Some New Label for Confirm Password'; 

$vars['page']['content']['system_main']['account']['pass']['pass2']['#title'] = 'Some Other  Label Confirm Password';
}
```

Comment: doesnot work for me in drupal 8

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution for Drupal 6, based on [theme_password_confirm](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_password_confirm/6):

```
function MYTHEME_password_confirm($element) {
  foreach (array('pass1', 'pass2') as $part) {
    $element[$part]['#attributes']['placeholder'] = $element[$part]['#title']; // Set the title text as placeholder
    unset($element[$part]['#title']); // Remove the title.
  }
  $element['#children'] = ''; // #children holds the html output
  foreach (element_children($element) as $key) {
    unset($element[$key]['#printed']); // Prepare to re-render.
    $element['#children'] .= drupal_render($element[$key]);
  }
  return theme('form_element', $element, $element['#children']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working solution for Drupal 7:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'user_profile_form'){
      // Here we need to provide an extra #process handler to allow us to modify
      // the password element that FAPI expands.
      $element_info = element_info('password_confirm');
      $process = $element_info['#process'];
      $process[] = 'MYMODULE_process_password_confirm';
      $form['account']['pass']['#process'] =  $process;
    }
}
  function MYMODULE_process_password_confirm($element) {
    $element['pass1']['#title'] = t("New Password");
    $element['pass2']['#title'] = t("Confirm New Password");
    return $element;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, hope it will work.

```
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {

   $form['account']['pass']['#process'] = array('form_process_password_confirm',  'register_alter_password_confirm');

}


function register_alter_password_confirm($element) {

   $element['pass1']['#title'] = t("Password:");

   $element['pass2']['#title'] = t("Confirm Password:");

   return $element;

}
```